# Отсутствует метод getText() в объекте класса Update при создании Telegram бота на java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, intellij-idea

Скорее всего данный вопрос максимально глупый, но тем не менее...
Создал Telegram бот на Java. Черед IDEA пытаюсь прописать обработку сообщений. Как я понял взаимодействие с ботом происходит через объекты класса Update. Но во всех инструкциях прочтенных мною, в данных объектах от класса Update наследуется метод getText(). В моем случае такой метод отсутствует. То ли нужно скачать какую-то дополнительную библиотеку, то ли та которая скачанная мной не полная... без понятия. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться...
Ниже прикреплю код бота и скриншот методов которые есть в объекте класса Update.

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "bot_name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "bot_token";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        System.out.println (update);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке прописать метод getText() вылетает ошибка:

```
Error:(18, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getText()
  location: variable update of type org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Update не содержится самого текста сообщения. Для доступа к тексту сообщения тебе нужно определить есть ли оно (метод `.hasMessage()`), потом достать его из Update методом `.getMessage()` и уже у конкретного Message взять текст методом `.getText()`.

Если кратко:

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    if (update.hasMessage()) {
        update.getMessage().getText();
        // работает при условии, что текст в сообщении есть
    }
}
```

Comment: И в правду, все заработало! Но все равно, объясните пожалуйста, почему изначально в объекте update не отображается наличие метода getText() а работает он только после данной проверки?

Comment: @Денис ну суть в том, что метод getText() содержится в объекте класса Message, который возвращается методом getMessage(), но в классе Update такого метода (getText()) просто нет.